# mongo db poor performance while doing text search with number

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called "torrents" with about 3.2M Documents. which basically contains public torrent metadata.

Schema:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let TorrentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  infohash: {type: String, index: true, unique: true},
  title: {type: String, index: true},
  category: {type: String, default: "Unknown", index: true},
  size: {type: Number, default: 0},
  trackers: [{
    downloads: {type: Number},
    peers: {type: Number},
    seeds: {type: Number},
    tracker: {type: String}
  }],
  files: [{path: String, length: Number}],
  swarm: {
    seeders: {type: Number, default: 0, index: -1},
    leechers: {type: Number, default: 0}
  },
  imported: {type: Date, default: Date.now, index: true},
  lastmod: {type: Date, default: Date.now, index: true}
});

TorrentSchema.virtual('getFiles').set(function () {
  return this.map(res => {
    if (typeof res === "string") return [{path: res, length: 0}];
    return res;
  })
});

TorrentSchema.virtual('downloads').get(function () {
  let downloads = 0;
  for (let download of this.trackers) {
    downloads += download.downloads
  }
  return downloads;
});

TorrentSchema.index({title: 'text'}, { language_override: 'none' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Torrent', TorrentSchema);
```

Now that the problem is when I am doing a text search with a keyword which also contents number(s) the search query taking a long time to execute.

```
  let q = req.query.q;
  q = q.split(/[\s]/).filter(n => n).map( str => `"${str}"`).join(" ");
  let PERPAGE = 20;
  let query = {$text: {$search: q}};
  // Tottent Is the same schema as above.
  let search = await Torrent.find(query).sort({"swarm.seeders" : -1}).select("-files").limit(PERPAGE).skip(skip);
```

now the issue is. when searching with letters like "ubuntu" it going really fast. but the problem arises when searching with a string which also contains numbers. Like "ubuntu 18", strings with no numbers like "ubuntu iso" taking nowhere near the time. the same thing happening when searching some other keywords like "somevideo 1080p", "somemovie 2" etc.

Do you have any fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, after querying with same keyword couple of times, the query speed seems increased significantly.